# Control the margin betwen LI element and its bullet

Tags: css, html-lists

I have a UL with LI elements inside. I am using a custom list bullet

```
list-style: url(images/att_remove3.png) outside;
```

I want to keep the bullet outside because not all the LI elements have bullets.

How do I control the margin between the LI text and the bullet?

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle with what you've got so far?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/au6T4/ < put a sample of your code in there, update/save and paste the link here please.

Comment: look here: http://jsfiddle.net/v6Xe2/  i want the bullet and the text to be closer

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a negative margin?

```
ul li { margin-left: -XXpx; }
```

Comment: that will move the bullet as well

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v6Xe2/1/ Here you go... I just added a span and gave it a negative margin, not sure if that's what you want but it works.

Comment: i want to do it without a span